# what's wrong with my git-svn command? cannot fork git.pm, why?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I was cloning a opensource project using git-svn, but failed.

this issue is different from https://superuser.com/questions/266338/git-svn-fails-with-fatal-error since i am not using cygwin this time:(

The error message is different as before, it just cannot fork:(

```
r6686 = f7adf2ab3ed10abac505b6ee5c88f983f3080e28 (refs/remotes/tags/NaiveBayes-1.0.1@8503)
Can't fork at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Git.pm line 1262.


real    550m4.292s
user    17m12.441s
sys     52m29.003s
```

git svn failed after 10 hours hardworking, what i can do after that?

Comment: Try running `git svn fetch` now. It should be able to pick up where it left off.

Comment: git svn fetch is erroneous to restart a broken git svn process, history maybe not complete on local side:(

Comment: What do you mean? git-svn is designed to be able to terminate at any time and resume the history fetch process by running `git svn fetch`.

Comment: just got the same error "Can't fork at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm line 1260" after 14 hr... did you find any solution???